# JsMockito verify mechanism doesn't work

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking

The **verify** mechanism of the JsMockito is not working for me. My setup is I have 2 classes, Common and Suggestions.

```
MyNS.Common = function() {};
MyNS.Suggestions = function() {};
```

I set in Suggestions an instance of Common.

```
MyNS.Suggestions.prototype.setCommon = function(common) {this.common = common;};
```

Then I use the returned value of Common.getAdGroupId() and invoke Suggestions.refresh() with this value. That's all that I want to test.

```
MyNS.Suggestions.prototype.init = function() {
    // This is mocked to return 56 as can be seen in the test above.
    var adGroupId = this.common.getAdGroupId();
    this.refresh(adGroupId);
};
```

The complete working example is on a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sbel/kqdTV/2/. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of errors here.

1. You have mocked out your system under test. You are testing MyNS.Suggestions, correct? Because it's a mock, the "init()" method is an empty stub. You need to use a real instance of the MyNS.Suggestions object.
2. You're calling "mockedSuggestions.setCommon(mockedCommon)". Because "setCommon" is a mocked method, it will do nothing. If you want to reference a value on a mocked object, you will need to do something like create a getter method ("getCommon"), then do "when(mockedSuggestions).getCommon().thenReturn(mockedCommon);". Of course, this is irrelevant, since the Suggestions object shouldn't be a mock in the first place.

Hope this helps!